# Evidence of optimality of sieve algorithms

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, big-picture, computational-number-theory, factorization

Sieve techniques apply to integer factoring and discrete logarithm to provide $2^{O(((\log n)(\log\log n)^2)^{1/3})}$ complexity for $n$ bit factoring and $n$ bit prime discrete logarithm.

The state of the art has not budged in a generation.

Is there evidence which indicates sieve techniques cannot be improved further?

Comment: @johncoleman Makes no sense to relate to $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$. There could be a different structurally different algorithm. Sieve algorithms do not speed-up $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems.